# Grails 2.4.5 config oracle connector

Tags: oracle, grails, ojdbc

I'm working on Grails 2.4.5 and I'd like to connect to oracle database.
On `DataSource.groovy` I added:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
    dbCreate = "update"
    url = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl'
    username = "root"
    password = "root"
    properties {
        // See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource for documentation
        jmxEnabled = false
        initialSize = 5
        maxActive = 50
        minIdle = 5
        maxIdle = 25
        maxWait = 10000
        maxAge = 10 * 60000
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
        validationQuery = "select 1 from dual"
        validationQueryTimeout = 3
        validationInterval = 15000
        testOnBorrow = true
        testWhileIdle = true
        testOnReturn = false
        jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState;StatementCache(max=200)"
        defaultTransactionIsolation = Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
    }
}
```

However when I run it I got bunches of error message:

> Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor':
>   Initialization of bean failed

Someone has done Grails with Oracle, please help me to get through.
Any solutions will be appreciated. Thanks.
Tran.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the ojdbc6.jar on your *lib* folder.

Also I'm not sure about localhost:1521:orcl, maybe it is localhost:1521/orcl where **orcl** should be the service name.